# how add mouse effect to gif

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry but I am starting with this and I would need to add some code that the mouse movement follow these gif files, for it, Could anybody help me?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img style="position:relative; TOP:400px; LEFT:600px; WIDTH:150px;
HEIGHT:120px; margin-right:-50px" border="0" src="trail6.gif">

<img style="position:relative; TOP:330px; LEFT:465px; WIDTH:70px;
HEIGHT:70px; margin-right:-50px" border="0" src="trail4.gif">

<img style="position:relative; TOP:340px; LEFT:600px; WIDTH:80px;
HEIGHT:80px; margin-right:-50px" border="0" src="trail2.gif">

<img style="position:relative; TOP:450px; LEFT:400px; WIDTH:80px;
HEIGHT:80px; margin-right:-50px" border="0" src="trail3.gif">


<img style="position:relative; TOP:450px; LEFT:550px; WIDTH:80px;
HEIGHT:80px; margin-right:-50px" border="0" src="trail5.gif">


</body>
</html>
```

Could anybody help me?
thanks in advance 
Alejandro Castan

Comment: You want the picture to follow the mouse pointer? In response to what event(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the MouseOver function of JavaScript.
Ready-to-use examples are to be found on the W3 site.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice

Comment: Hi zeepost, First thanks for your help. On the other hand maybe I do not explain very well what I am looking for and it is similar to this one http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/trailer.htm  but I would like that the gif images are in the same place add in the code thanks again

Comment: Hi I found one Jqueryscript for my needs but I can see the gif file. Surely I am making a mistake the code is the following: